# Banning people from Facebook group using the Graph API for PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-group

Hi I am developing an app to use along with a journal-system for managing a facebook group.

For this system i wish to impliment a way to ban specific users, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, anyway this is the code i use for it.

```
    try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api(
            '{actual group id}/members/{user id of the guy i am trying to ban}',
            'DELETE'
        );
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getType();
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

And this is the error message outputted by getType() and getMessage() :

OAuthException(#3) Unknown method

my scope include "manage_pages"

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation:

> Apps can remove people from groups that app has created
>
> An app access token can remove any app users from a group created by that app.

So if the app did not create the user then it cannot remove it.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group/members)

Comment: Correctly: So if the app did not create the group then it cannot remove the user from the group.